# Is there an alternate way to handle large 2D arrays in Java, given a memory constraint?

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a 2D coordinate system using a 2D `int` array in Java. I have a memory constraint of 256MB, and the 2D grid is large enough for the memory requirement to go beyond that. Is there another data structure that can do this, while consuming lesser memory?

(Edit: The intent is to track movement within the grid by setting flags for the coordinates that have been visited at least once.)

Comment: Try `java.nio.Buffer`

Comment: Only keep the part in memory that you're currently using (i.e. a viewport or something comparable) and keep the rest in storage

Comment: It really depends on what you actually do with that array. Could you elaborate on what kind of data gets written to it (maybe you don't need the full 32bit of the int type), how you write to it (maybe you don't need a fully allocated array, but can work with a dynamic map, because most indices remain empty anyways), how you read from it (maybe you can store the entire thing somewhere and always just load a specific chunk to work with as others have suggested), and any other information that could be useful to be able to help you.

Comment: @MaxVollmer I'm trying to track movement you can say. Whenever a point on the 2D grid is visited, the programs sets a flag at those coordinates, so that if the same point is revisited, the flag can tell that. I could use a `boolean` array because it's just really a true/false thing, but even that doesn't help the memory issue.

Comment: Please update your question with that information.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array for that at all. You are wasting memory for every point right now, while you actually only need to store coordinates of visited points. Use a set of points to store only the coordinates that have been visited, and check if the set contains coordinates to see if a point was visited before or not.

**So instead of:**

```
int[][] array = new int[width][height];
```

and

```
array[x][y] = true;
```

and

```
if (array[x][y] == true) {...}
```

**you have something like:**

```
class Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        return o instanceof Point && this.x == ((Point)o).x && this.y == ((Point)o).y;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return Integer.valueOf(x).hashCode() ^ Integer.valueOf(y).hashCode();
    }
}

Set<Point> set = new HashSet<Point>();
```

and

```
if (set.contains(new Point(x, y))) {...}
```

and

```
set.add(new Point(x,y));
```

**Alternatively you could use a map:**

```
HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

and

```
if (map.contains(x) && map.get(x).contains(y)) {...}
```

and

```
if (!map.contains(x)) {
    map.add(x, new HashSet<Integer>());
}
map.get(x).add(y);
```

**Further optimization options**

If you know that your application will visit all points or at least more than half of all points, you can switch the logic when it reached 50% of points visited. Basically (pseudocode):

```
if (pointsVisited < numAllPoints / 2)
    values in map or set are visited
else
    values in map or set are **not** visited (all others are)
```

You of course need some method that actually does a swap when the threshold is reached, removing all points from your map or set and adding all that weren't in there before. Afterwards instead of adding points, you remove points when they get visited.

That way at most half of all points are stored at any given time.

Comment: Yeah, this makes so much more sense. I had thought of using the alternate method of storing just the coordinates of the points visited (as you explained), but even for that, I used a 2D array, and searched for each new entry through all the entries already present in the array (to see if it's already present, and hence visited). That would simply create a huge calculations overhead and slow down the whole process. No doubt, this is a far better approach. Thank you.